# Laravel morphMany Returning Null id

Tags: laravel, relationship

I'm trying to create Favorites for Replies, I have these models

App\Reply

```
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Favorite', 'favorited');
}
```

App\Favorite

```
public function favorited()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Here is my DB table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('favorites', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('favorited_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('favorited_type', 50);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique(['user_id', 'favorited_id', 'favorited_type']);
    });
}
```

When I try to create a new favorite like this:

```
public function store(Reply $reply){
    Favorite::create([
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'favorited_id' => $reply->id,
        'favorited_type' => get_class($reply)
    ]);
    return back();
}
```

I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'favorited_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `favorites` (`user_id`, `favorited_id`, `favorited_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (4, , App\Reply, 2018-03-06 04:27:11, 2018-03-06 04:27:11))
```

Someone please help me here.

Comment: Try dumping the `$reply` with `dd($reply)` to see why `$reply->id` returns null.

Comment: Thank you very much... I tried that and finally found the problem in my route file. I used Route::post('replies/{favorite}/favorite'... instead of Route::post('replies/{reply}/favorite'.

Comment: You need to update your migration $table->integer('favorited_id')->nullable()->unsigned();

Or you may create an update migration

Comment: Also if you don't want it to be nullable() Please confirm $reply->id returning data.